# Website not deploying using Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am creating a website and I wanted to put it online. However how many times I would try to deploy it using the Google App Engine Launcher it would not deploy.

app.yaml file :

```
application: GameDroidWeb
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

main.py :

```
# Copyright 2012 Digital Inspiration
# http://www.labnol.org/

import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Deployment Console Log :

```
2014-05-13 22:53:29 Running command: "['C:\\Python33\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=TheAddictedGamerOfficial@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\WEBSITE TEST']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined
2014-05-13 22:53:29 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have tried un-installing and reinstalling but that did not work either. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You are using python 3 , you need Python 2.7.

*(The Python SDK is not compatible with Python 3.)* from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/devenvironment)

Comment: Good call. I had both 2.7 and 3 installed on my machine and the GAE launcher was selecting version 3 by default. Overriding the Python path to point to 2.7 in the Preferences window of the launcher resolved the issue for me.